# Como criar múltiplas colunas utilizando os valores de uma no pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(repeat_R)
print(df)
```

O dataframe que eu tenho é assim:

`0
0   0.583822
1   0.582975
2   0.541191
3   0.526122
4   0.547239
5   0.555875
6   0.556838
7   0.524316
8   0.594906
9   0.559264
10  0.551321
11  0.530168
12  0.566200
13  0.499690
14  0.552580
15  0.523648
16  0.573826
17  0.554709
18  0.566220
19  0.505065
20  0.573585
21  0.586732
22  0.565730
23  0.534764
24  0.593547
25  0.573899
26  0.562164
27  0.529680
28  0.578324
29  0.484839
30  0.552086
31  0.549009
32  0.549631
33  0.499424
34  0.542479
35  0.511983
36  0.558355
37  0.491869
38  0.548544
39  0.485955`

Eu quero que o novo dataframe tenha na primeira coluna os 10 primeiros valores, na segunda os 10 segundos valores, na terceira os 10 terceiros valores e na quarta os 10 quartos valores. Eu tentei dividir o dataframe original em quatro dataframes e depois juntar um só, mas não da certo:

```
df1 = df.iloc[0:9]
print(df1)
df2 = df.iloc[10:19]
print(df2)
df3 = df.iloc[20:29]
print(df3)
df4=df.iloc[30:39]
print(df4)
result = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4], axis=1, join='inner')
```

Alguém saberia como solucionar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apresento abaixo minha solução. É uma implementação particular de um princípio mais geral que pode ser utilizado para implementar uma solução mais simples. O princípio é: crie listas com os valores de cada coluna separadamente e então use o *dataframe constructor*  do pandas (`pd.DataFrame`) para criar o novo dataframe. Segue:

```
import pandas as pd

def reshape(inf, sup, data):
    return [float(i) for i in data.iloc[inf:sup,:].values]

pd.DataFrame({'A': reshape(0,10, df) ,'B': reshape(10,20, df), 
              'C': reshape(20,30, df), 'D': reshape(30,40, df)}, index = range(10))
```

Resultado:

```
       A           B            C          D
0   0.583822    0.551321    0.573585    0.552086
1   0.582975    0.530168    0.586732    0.549009
2   0.541191    0.566200    0.565730    0.549631
3   0.526122    0.499690    0.534764    0.499424
4   0.547239    0.552580    0.593547    0.542479
5   0.555875    0.523648    0.573899    0.511983
6   0.556838    0.573826    0.562164    0.558355
7   0.524316    0.554709    0.529680    0.491869
8   0.594906    0.566220    0.578324    0.548544
9   0.559264    0.505065    0.484839    0.485955
```

Comment: Obrigado Hartnäckig! Funcionou perfeito, era bem isso que eu precisava!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) com o [`transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html) do numpy sem a necessidade de escrever manualmente uma função ou chama-la várias vezes.

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, 10).T, columns=['A','B', 'C', 'D'])

#saida
    A           B           C           D
0   0.583822    0.551321    0.573585    0.552086
1   0.582975    0.530168    0.586732    0.549009
2   0.541191    0.566200    0.565730    0.549631
3   0.526122    0.499690    0.534764    0.499424
4   0.547239    0.552580    0.593547    0.542479
5   0.555875    0.523648    0.573899    0.511983
6   0.556838    0.573826    0.562164    0.558355
7   0.524316    0.554709    0.529680    0.491869
8   0.594906    0.566220    0.578324    0.548544
9   0.559264    0.505065    0.484839    0.485955
```